# Nested "Return" to Exit Parent Function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My goal is to check a condition and exit out of the current function. HOWEVER, I would prefer to do it in another function called from the function I want to exit. Simple example that does NOT call a separate function and just check for condition in body:

```
$scope.doStuff = function(){
  if (something) {  
    return;
  }
  doSomething();
}
```

Can the part below...

```
  if (something) {  
    return;
  }
```

...be placed in a function that can be used in doStuff(), like so?

```
$scope.doStuff = function(){
  $scope.exitOnCondition();
  doSomething();
}

$scope.exitOnCondition){
      if (something) {  
        return;
      }
}
```

Obviously in the way I wrote it, the "return" will return out of the exitOnCondition function, not doStuff. As usual, I don't need the code checked, just a general example, everything here is just to illustrate the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have `exitOnCondition` return a boolean, and call it in an `if` statement.

```
$scope.doStuff = function(){
  if ($scope.exitOnCondition())
    return;
  doSomething();
}

$scope.exitOnCondition = function(){
      if (something) {  
        return true;
      }
}
```

To avoid the `return` in the main function, you could restructure it a little but the `if` will need to stay.

```
$scope.doStuff = function(){
  if (!$scope.exitOnCondition())
    doSomething();
}

$scope.exitOnCondition = function(){
      if (something) {  
        return true;
      }
}
```

Notice the `!` negation of the result. This can be a little cleaner if you reverse the meaning of the `exitOnCondition()` function.

```
$scope.doStuff = function(){
  if ($scope.passedCondition())
    doSomething();
}

$scope.passedCondition = function(){
      if (something) {  
        return false;
      }
}
```

Comment: My goal is to avoid the "return" in there, it seems, based on both your answers, that what I am trying to do is impossible directly. Is that correct? Ty for the reply.

Comment: @VSO: You could `throw`, but it will need to be caught somewhere. Only other way to avoid `return` in the main function would be to restructure your code so that the rest only executes if the other function returns true. `if ($scope.passedCondition()) { doSomething() }`

Comment: Hmm, that seems awfully convoluted, but definitely useful if the exit condition is a complicated check. I was trying to one-line it and wondering if I didn't know some 101 stuff. I understand now, thank you for the answer, I will accept it when the five min timer runs down.

Comment: @VSO: I think the only way to get what you're looking for would be if JavaScript had some sort of templating system, where code could be injected. It doesn't have anything like that. You may be able to do some nasty `eval()` solution, but let's not go there. :-) *EDIT:* The nasty `eval` didn't work for me, so that seems to be off the table.

Comment: Haha eval(). But yea, your answer is exactly what I was looking for, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You could have `exitOnCondition` return a value which you can check in the parent function.

```
$scope.exitOnCondition = function() {
  if (something) {
    return true;
  }
  // ...
  return false; // Could omit this entirely
};

$scope.doStuff = function() {
  if ($scope.exitOnCondition()) {
    return;
  }
  doSomething();
};
```